# Python: Real-Time Plotting Y axis Problem

Tags: python, matplotlib, serial-port, real-time, graphing

I'm currently trying to plot some data in real-time from a sensor. Unfortunately, No matter how many different methods I use, be it plot(x,y), animation, or drawnow. I am constantly running into this error.

For some reason, I can't seem to create a fixed Y axis. I want it to be a set range between 0 and 5. But everytime I start to data, the first data point it reads becomes the origin (bottom left) and as I decrease the value, the graph moves in the positive Y direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am reading the data through a serial port.

[image: Problem as seen]

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = []
ys = []
xval =0

# Initialize communication with Photodiode
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
print ('Available Ports:\n')
for p in ports:
    print (p)

Serialport= input("\n Type in the port associate with Arduino\n(For example, 
                  Type in 'COM8' without the '): \n")
ser = serial.Serial(Serialport, 9600)


# This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate(i, xs, ys):
    global xval
    # Read data from serial port and convert to list.
    reading = ser.readline().decode()
    Incominglist = str(reading).split(",")

    # Add x and y to lists
    ys.extend(Incominglist)

   for val in range(len(Incominglist)):
       if  xval == 0 and val ==0:
           xs.append(xval)  # Beginning X Value to 0
       else:
           xval += 0.0001
           xs.append(xval) #increases X by increment 0.0001

    # Draw x and y lists
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)

    # Format plot
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)


# Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to plot numbers, instead of strings.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Oh man that's embarrassing. Totally didn't see that I hadn't converted those to floats.. Thanks